# Remove a specific word from a string

Tags: java, replace

I'm trying to remove a specific word from a certain string using the function `replace()` or `replaceAll()` but these remove all the occurrences of this word even if it's part of another word!

*Example:*

```
String content = "is not like is, but mistakes are common";
content = content.replace("is", "");
```

**output:** `"not like , but mtakes are common"`

**desired output:** `"not like , but mistakes are common"`

How can I substitute only whole words from a string?

Comment: Are you required to use replace? With string? Do you have to search for different strings to replace to and from?

Comment: you should add in which part of all your string you want to replace, maybe you can use a regular expression to do the work

Answer (score 46, accepted):

What the heck,

```
String regex = "\\s*\\bis\\b\\s*";
content = content.replaceAll(regex, "");
```

Remember you need to use `replaceAll(...)` to use regular expressions, not `replace(...)`

- `\\b` gives you the word boundaries
- `\\s*` sops up any white space on either side of the word being removed (if you want to remove this too).

Comment: There is still one problem left. If the sentense was 'dog is cat', this code removes the space from both side of the word 'is' and make it 'dogcat'. I think its better to write `content = content.replaceAll(regex," ")` and then trim the spaces at the ends

Answer (score 5):

`content = content.replaceAll("\\Wis\\W|^is\\W|\\Wis$", "");`

Comment: don't you need `replaceAll(...)` not `replace(...)` to use the magic of regular expressions?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Sorry didn't test. Edited after testing. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try replacing " is " by " ". The is with a space before and one after, replaced by a single space.

Update:

To make it work for the first "is" in the sentence, also do another replace of "is " for "". Replacing the first is and the first space, with an empty string.

Comment: Since you might have to handle that case specially because of the capital letter, perhaps multiple `replaceAll()` calls would work?  Including a `replaceAll(" is\.",".");` or somesuch to catch the last one...

Comment: You're both right. Thank you. I have updated the answer to include that case. If the string would end in " is", that case would also have to be added though, adding to a total of 3. Also, like Rob then added, the upper case cases should also be contemplated in additional replaceAll calls.

Answer (score 0):

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        String input = s.nextLine();
        char c = s.next().charAt(0);
        System.out.println(removeAllOccurrencesOfChar(input, c));
    }


    public static String removeAllOccurrencesOfChar(String input, char c) {
   String r = "";
   for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i ++) {
      if (input.charAt(i) != c) r += input.charAt(i);
      }
   return r;
      }
    }
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your code such that others can learn from it

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem in the question. The OP wants to remove all occurrences of `is`. Your code removes all occurrences of the first character.